# Eigenvalues and spectrum of the adjoint

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

In a finite-dimensional Hilbert space, the eigenvalues of the adjoint $A^*$ of an operator $A$ are the complex conjugates of the eigenvalues of $A$.

But in infinite dimensions this need no longer be the case. For example, an annihilation operator $a$ has all complex numbers as eigenvalues (and coherent states as normalizable eigenstates), while the creation operator $a^*$, its adjoint, has no eigenvalues. Here $a$ and $a^*$ act on a Hilbert space with a fixed countable orthonormal basis written as $|n\rangle$ ($n=0,1,2,,\ldots$) as 
$$a|n\rangle=\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle,~~~a^*|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle.$$
(The terminology is as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator.)

What is the general relation between the eigenvalues of an operator $A$ densely defined on a Hilbert space and those of its adjoint? What is their relation with the spectrum defined as the set of $x$ such that $xI-A$ has no bounded inverse?

As the comments so far showed, the spectrum of both $a$ and $a^*$ is the complex plane. For self-adjoint operators, for each point in the interior of the continuous spectrum, there are apparently unnormalizable eigenstates in the dual of a dense nuclear subspace. Does this generalize to general closed operators? What would these generalized eigenstates be in the case of $a^∗$?

Comment: For a closed densely defined linear operator $A$ on a Hilbert space, the spectrum of $A^*$ is in fact always the complex conjugate of the spectrum of $A$, just as in the finite-dimensional case (see for instance Theorem III.6.22 in "T. Kato: Perturbation theory for linear operators" (1980)). To better understand your example, a reference or a precise definition of $a$ would probably be helpful (since the notions "annihilation operator" and "creation operator" seem to be used in various contexts in quantum physics).

Comment: @JochenGlueck: I defined the operators and gave a link.

Comment: I suspect that you are confusing the spectrum with the eigenspectrum. Indeed, eigenvalues of an operator need not be eigenvalues of the adjoint.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: What is their difference, and how are they related to each other?

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Spectrum_of_the_adjoint_operator

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! To expand on @MichaelRenardy's comment: It is true that, in your example, $a^*$ has no eigenvalues, so its eigenspectrum (i.e. the set of its eigenvalues; many people also call it the *point spectrum*) is empty. However, the spectrum of $a^*$ (which is, in general, a larger set than the point spectrum), is not empty but coincides with the complex conjugate of the spectrum of $a$, i.e. with the complex plane.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: For self-adjoint operators, for each point in the continuous spectrum, there are unnormalizable eigenstates in the dual of a dense nuclear subspace. Does this generalize to general closed operators? What would be these generalized eigenstates in the case of $a^*$?

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: Unfortunately, I don't know.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier There must be something in the air, because I was just mentioning the fact that that isn't true [elsewhere](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349245/is-there-a-reasonable-notion-of-spectral-theorem-on-a-pre-hilbert-space/349276#comment875155_349276). Consider the operator $T|n\rangle = \frac{1}{n+1}|n\rangle$. It is self-adjoint, its eigenvalues are $\frac{1}{n+1}$ for each $n = 0,1,2,\ldots$, but additionally it is not invertible, so $0$ is a spectral value (and part of the continuous spectrum).

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier But there is no corresponding generalized eigenvector (when $T$ is considered as an operator on the nuclear space $s$ of sequences that rapidly converge to $0$)

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier The spectrum of the creation operator $a^*$ is all "residual spectrum", *i.e.* the kernel of $a^* - \lambda$ is $\{0\}$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, but the range of $a^* - \lambda$ is not dense, essentially because the bra $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n}{\sqrt{n!}} \langle n |$ vanishes on the image of $a^{*}$, so it doesn't have closed range. As a result, I think it would be difficult to find any kind of eigenvector for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ in this case, even if you allow "eigenvectors" outside the Hilbert space.

Comment: @RobertFurber: So the continuous spectrum of $T$ is the discrete set $\{0\}$?

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier Yes.

Comment: @RobertFurber: Do generalized eigenvectors always exist in the interior of the continuous spectrum of a self-adjoint operator?

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier I don't know.

Comment: Note also that your definition of spectrum is the one for (works only for) bounded operators. Check out the general one for the unbounded case.

Comment: @lcv To whom are you addressing your comment? Use the @ symbol before the user name. The definition of spectrum for an unbounded is given in the Wikipedia article that András Bátkai linked to, and doesn't make any difference to the discussion (the spectrum of $T$ is still the same, and I already had to be using the unbounded definition for $a^*$ because it's an unbounded operator).

Comment: @RobertFurber I was talking to the OP. In the original post the spectrum was defined as the set of points for which $x - A$ is not invertible.

Comment: @lcv: Yes, I corrected my statement after having reading your comment! Thanks for pointing this out.